Flag response time?
I flagged an answer as "not an answer" on April 28, since I thought it didn't really address the specific concerns of the question. (Whether or not that is true doesn't seem entirely obvious, now that I think of it, but that's not the point here.) I've been wondering about whether or not my flagging was correct, so I've periodically checked my profile page to see if this has been addressed.
But it's now May 7, and the flag still shows up as "pending" on my profile page. This, assuming it's not a bug, seems like a really long time. (For comparison: flags on Anime & Manga seem to get answered within a day. I flagged a question as "duplicate" at around the same time as I flagged the answer here on English Language and Usage, and that got resolved within a week.)
Is there any reason why this should be the case? To me, the most obvious reasons for this would be low or infrequent participation by users with enough rep to access review queues, and that seems worrying.

I try to do a chunk now and then but it takes time if there aren't many people reviewing the queue. 
But let me use this opportunity to say something: Sometimes I see "not an answer" flags for answers that are low-quality answers. This is not the appropriate use of this flag.
There is already a way to signal low quality answers, and that is downvoting. "Not an answer" flags are for posts that do not even address the question or talk about something unrelated.

I have the exact same concern. IMHO, I believe there is probably enough user with high reputation for the purpose of review queue. I assume the problem is that some users are either not as dedicated, not as informed to make a thoughtful judgement, or perhaps unaware of the review queue's feature. (I mean, impossible is nothing)
I think this meta site is good reflection of the activeness of the community. (I posted a question here a week ago and it only has 13 views with zero activity) And from a conversation I had with @Ming (@setek on chat.SE), some people in mainland China report that SE sites are all blocked by the great firewall, so that doesn't help to get experts on board. 
I do hope we can do something about it though. Once the blog for Chinese.SE is launched (has it?), I'd like to create some entries and hopefully attract more attention. I believe there are many potential users in the States, not to mention the Chinese-speaking population worldwide.

Yeah, it's weird since I looked at the Area51 stats, and while we're perhaps slightly lacking in views and questions asked, the number of users, at least according to the numbers they gave, didn't seem particularly worrying at all.

@Maroon Yeah, exactly what I thought. Do you have any thought to my question?
